# Code Ignitor - under login / session load MySQL CPU spike and Fatal MySQL Deadlock

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, session, amazon-rds, deadlock

I have a site using:

- AWS RDS (MySQL Aurora) - single t3.medium instance
- 4 x EC2s on a Load Balancer (fixed instances not elastic)
- CodeIgnitor 3 codebase (3.1.7)

Some specs:

**EC2s:**

```
PHP Version 7.2.32-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
Linux ip-172-32-19-104 5.4.0-1028-aws #29~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 6 17:14:23 UTC 2020 x86_64
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
```

**RDS:**

```
5.6.mysql_aurora.1.22.2
Instance class: db.t3.medium
vCPU: 2
RAM: 4 GB
```

Under heavy load (500 people trying to log in in the space of ten mintues), we experience intermittant but significant issues. It's been hard to get information on exactly what users are experiencing but things point to:

- The RDS MySQL Aurora CPU spikes significantly (100%)
- The RDS MySQL Aurora Connections spikes (30-45) - From what I've read, the RDS Max Connections is {DBInstanceClassMemory/12582880}, so around 340 4GB(1024*4*1024*1024)/12582880
- **The resulting error `Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`** - see below for full error trace.

I have made the, perhaps incorrect, asusmption that it's therefore:

1. increase load >> increase RDS CPU usage
2. high RDS CPU >> Deadlocks >> Fatal MySQL Error (I'm not too familar on Deadlocks to know if this is what can happen but sounds feasible).

The error points to `libaries\Session\drivers\Session_database_driver.php`, specifically:

```
     /**
     * Write
     *
     * Writes (create / update) session data
     *
     * @param   string  $session_id Session ID
     * @param   string  $session_data   Serialized session data
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function write($session_id, $session_data)

   ...
   ...
   ...
   if ($this->_db->update($this->_config['save_path'], $update_data))
        {
            $this->_fingerprint = md5($session_data);
            return $this->_success;
        }
```

So, we're getting a database Deadlock when trying to update the CI Session.

It seems to always throw the error during the user's login process, which I presume is update session heavy.

This session and database class is as per the CI 3.1.7 codebase.

The current Code Ignitor Session config is as follows:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

So, if my assumption is correct, what would be the best plan of action:

1. **Move to RDS Serverless and let the RDS scale to handle CPU load?** (I read somewhere that Serverless might not handle locks well, as it can't scale properly when it's in lock... my understanding on that is obviously limited)
2. **Move to a bigger, fixed (non serverless) RDS to handle CPU Load?** (not ideal as 95% of the time the site has no traffic)
3. **Amend sessions to be stored in files instead of database** - this to me sounds logical as then we take all of the session load away from the MySQL, but I am not fully aware of any other consequences, nor if it's just a case of amending `$config['sess_driver']` and setting up the session file folder path
4. **Something else...***

With option 3), we use an Load Balancer, so I worry that file based sessions would mean loss of a user's session if they switch LB mid-way though. Although, this may be a managable issue, since the user will stay on the LB for the duration of their stay unless it falls over mid-way.

Options 1 and 2 seem like band aid approaches rather than fixing an ineffecient problem, but then, it could simply be a case of not enough resources.

I read elsewhere a sugestion on a similarish post to use php-fpm to reduce the number of simulaneous apache threads, but not sure if that's relevant here.

It's hard to 'test' as it only happens under large user-login load, so some suggestions would be really appreciated, so I don't have to take multiple stabs in the dark.

Thanks

EDIT:

Copy of full error below:

```
A Database Error Occurred 

Error Number: 1213 

Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction 

UPDATE `ci_sessions` SET `timestamp` = 1604298368 WHERE `id` = 'fqi83a50dfknbvl9h2r98mtgn2f3j2j6' Filename: libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php 

Line Number: 260 

A PHP Error was encountered 

Severity: Warning 

Message: Unknown: Cannot call session save handler in a recursive manner 

Filename: Unknown 

Line Number: 0 
Backtrace: 

A PHP Error was encountered 

Severity: Warning 

Message: Unknown: Failed to write session data using user defined save handler. (session.save_path: /var/lib/php/sessions) 

Filename: Unknown 

Line Number: 0 

Backtrace
```

Comment: try to update to 3.1.11., there have been some session issues in earlier 3.x versions

Comment: @Vickel - I've just upgraded to 3.1.11 thanks; I see from the changelog there were a decent few improvements to sessions, especially in more recent ones. We've also thrown more RDS resource at it (Serverless with 4x starting point). Wondering if there's any merit looking at php-fpm, bearing in mind we're already 7.2

Comment: I think the remaining parts of your question you might want to ask at https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Have posted on serverfault - https://serverfault.com/questions/1041044/codeignitor-under-login-session-load-mysql-cpu-spike-and-fatal-mysql-deadloc